# List of files in a project visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-sdk

I'm working with the Visual studio 2010 SDK, developing an extension. I'm trying to get a list of all the files in a project, however currently I cannot get the list of files within a filter. All that I can see returned is the filter name, and the number of files inside that filter.

I'm currently using the [ProjectItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem) interface, specifically the [FileNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem.filenames)Property. However, in their documentation for this they say:

> When the project item's ProjectItems property has a value, and the ProjectItem object represents a filter folder on the disk, then the FileNames property returns only the name of the filter folder.

Is there another method that I can use to list the files inside a filter, or am I tackling this the wrong way?

Answer (score 4):

So, I've made enough progress on this to continue. I only need to use this extension in a Visual C++ project, so I was able to use  the [VCProject Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169441) to get a list of projects, and the [VCProject Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcproject.files) property to get the list of files from the projects.
Something like this

```
        VCProject prj;
        int count = _applicationObject.Solution.Projects.Count;
        for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++ )
        {
            //Start counting at one for some reason
            prj = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.VCProject)_applicationObject.Solution.Projects.Item(i).Object;

            foreach (VCFile item in prj.Files)
            {
                //Item is the file, do whatever you want with it here
            }
        }
```

I would still like to know if there is a way to do this for all projects(not just VisualC++).